# Dynamically Created Top Articles List in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm creating a Django-powered site for my newspaper-ish site. The least obvious and common-sense task that I have come across in getting the site together is how best to generate a "top articles" list for the sidebar of the page.

The first thing that came to mind was some sort of database column that is updated (based on what?) with every view. That seems (to my instincts) ridiculously database intensive and impractical and thus I think I'd like to find another solution.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give [celery](http://ask.github.com/celery/getting-started/introduction.html) a try (with django-celery). While it's not so easy to configure and use as cache, it enables you to queue tasks like incrementing counters and do them in background. It could be even combined with cache technique - in views increment counters in cache and define PeriodicTask that will run every now and then, resetting counters and writing them to the database.

I just remembered - I once found [this blog entry](http://blog.damontimm.com/django-hitcount-app-count-hits-views/) which provides nice way of incrementing 'viewed_count' (or similar) column in database with AJAX JS call. If you don't have heavy traffic maybe it's good idea?

Also mentioned in this post is [django-tracking](http://code.google.com/p/django-tracking/), but I don't know much about it, I never used it myself (yet).

Answer (score 1):

Premature optimization, first try the db way and then see if it really is too database sensitive. Any decent database has so good caches it probably won't matter very much. And even if it is a problem, take a look at the other db/cache suggestions here.

It is most likely by the way is that you will have many more intensive db queries with each view than a simple view update.

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like sort by top views, it would be fast if you index the view column in the DB.  Another option is to only collect the top x articles every hour or so, and toss that value into Django's cache framework.

The nice thing about caching the list is that the algorithm you use to determine top articles can be as complex as you like without hitting the DB hard with every page view.  Django's cache framework can use memory, db, or file system.  I prefer DB, but many others prefer memory.  I believe it uses pickle, so you can also store Python objects directly. It's easy to use, recommended.

Answer (score 0):

An index wouldn't help as them main problem I believe is not so much getting the sorted list as having a DB write with **every page view** of an article. Another index actually makes that problem worse, albeit only a little.

So I'd go with the cache. I think django's cache shim is a problem here because it requires timeouts on all keys. I'm not sure if that's imposed by memcached, if not then go with redis. Actually just go with redis anyway, the python library is great, I've used it from django projects before, and it has atomic increments and powerful sorting - everything you need.